# No-go theorem evasion for higher spin (super)string theory

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, higher-spin

The inclusion of (conventional) SUSY truncates spin states in (super)string theory and M-theory.

My question here is the following: could a non-standard SUSY algebra be constructed in such a way (super)string theory states with $J>2$ could be coherently introduced? If we relax this condition to non-supersymmetric superstring theories, but we relax Lorentz invariance too, could higher spin states be included?